# Is there a better, existing word for “antifragility”?

Tags: synonyms, neologisms

Nassim Taleb, on a [recent episode](http://www.econtalk.org/archives/2012/01/taleb_on_antifr.html) of *Econtalk*, talks about his upcoming book that aims to coin the word *antifragility*. The essential meaning is close to the phrase “What doesn’t kill you makes you stronger” — a system or process that benefits from volatility, stress, or uncertainty. Examples:

> Human bones are *antifragile*; they [benefit from the stress of gravity](http://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2001/ast02aug_1/) and weaken without it.
>
> In terms of forest fires, forests are *antifragile* — too much firefighting can cause more damage in the long run.

Taleb [writes about why he needed the word](http://edge.org/q2011/q11_3.html#taleb):

> So let us coin the appellation "antifragile" for anything that, on average, (i.e., in expectation) benefits from variability. Alas, I found no simple, noncompound word in any of the main language families that expresses the point of such fragility in reverse. To see how alien the concept to our minds, ask around what's the antonym of fragile. The likely answer will be: robust, unbreakable, solid, well-built, resilient, strong, something-proof (say waterproof, windproof, rustproof), etc. Wrong — and it is not just individuals, but branches of knowledge that are confused by it; this is a mistake made in every dictionary.

In short, words like *robust* and *resilient* don’t suggest favorability toward adverse conditions.

My question: is there a better word that exists?

Comment: I thought there was a word that means "thrives in adverse conditions" but I can't seem to find it. `Extremophile` is about as close as I could come up with, and that's a pretty specific term, but one could come up with an adjective out of it.  I don't think he's quite right though, it's not that they benefit from stress, but instead that they benefit from the environment and circumstances which they evolved to cope with, and indeed, often cannot survive well or at all without that environment because they don't have the mechanisms to cope with the new stuff, even if it may seem less stressful.

Comment: I'd quibble that the word he is looking for would not really be the antonym of "fragile". "Fragile" means "easily broken, lacking strength". So logically the antonym would be a word meaning "not easily broken" or "having strength", like "durable" or "robust". In any case, I don't have an answer to the question, I just don't like "antifragile" as an answer either.

Comment: I'd probably go for "adaptive", but that merely implies changing in accord with one's environment, not that it's better for said object to be in adverse conditions.

Comment: @Jay — I agree with you, and this is partly why I asked the question! :)

Comment: @Phoenix But we do talk of environments that are more or less stressful. Whether something is "meant" to cope with it is another matter.

Comment: [resilient](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=resilient): Able to recover readily, as from misfortune. Why does this word not capture what you're after?

Comment: @Gnawme I don't think it suggests that adversity is beneficial, nor that stability or comfort is damaging, both of which Taleb wants to convey.

Comment: We only call some things "extremophiles" because they live in environments which *humans* would find extreme. Like everything else alive, they'll have evolved so that from their point of view, they live in ideal conditions. As do certain forests - they survive the fire, while their competitors get killed off. No living thing actually **thrives** (usually, it can't *survive*) in environments which are seriously adverse *from its point of view*.

Comment: imho, Taleb is just a tub-thumper. *Robust* is a perfectly good antonym of *fragile*, and his concept of "antifragile" is of limited applicability - he actually just means **resilient**, but he's confusing survival of the species/system with survival of the **individual**. I'm voting to close as "not constructive"

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree that that Robust is a good antonym of fragile. That's why I think "antifragility" isn't a good term for the concept Taleb is sketching out.

Comment: I don't think there really is a single word term for something that breaks or dies or whatever when stress is removed from it.  Imagine a metal bar that can hold a load of tons as long as the load is on it, but remove the load and the bar shatters (for whatever imaginary reason. Non-Newtonian metal?).  It certainly wouldn't be considered robust or resilient or anything like that.  It would be both fragile and not fragile at the same time.

Comment: @mjhoy: Well, I'm not going to devote too much time to researching Taleb's "philosophy" here, though I'm guessing he'll still be banging on about the instability of global financial markets. But in the end all I see is an almost wanton muddying of the difference between individual and "group" survival - where "group" could be any level from small partnerships to global corporations to capitalism to humanity itself. The higher levels effectively *require* potentially fatal changes to happen at lower levels - survival of the fittest is what drives evolution in the first place.

Comment: I would say that no; there is no better word for this inane concept, and Taleb should keep it so as not to sully any other perfectly good existing words. It's a word in the same way that "Exxon" and "Microsoft" are words; it's a trademark marketing catchphrase like "snacktivity" or "crantastic".

Comment: I agree with the tub-thumping assessment. "Anti-fragility" makes me feel exasperated. Robust, durable, resilient, survivable (as in "survival of the fittest" or "adaptable"), flexible, having high tensile strength, adaptable, tempered (as in steel), ductility... Taleb could use any of these words alone or in combination. @MarkBeadles and FumbleFingers are correct, in my irritable opinion.

Comment: Whether Taleb is tub-thumping or not, I still think that robust/resilient/etc do not really convey a sense of "benefitting from adverse conditions" and that if he instead used a combination of those antonyms, Taleb would be more confusing than he already is. In that way I think @DavidR is right, using a new word helps him communicate the concept. I also don't think it's inane, but hopefully we can agree it _is_ a concept.

Comment: I must rise to Mr Taleb's defense here for a moment: Just based on the brief quotes above, it appears Taleb is drawing a distinction between durable or resilient, meaning able to withstand or adapt to stress, and saying that something thrives under stress. Surely the latter is true of many things, e.g. muscles develop best when exercised. Whether I agree with whatever ultimate point he makes I don't know, not having looked up the article to read where he goes with this. But it's a real-world concept and thus fair to ask for a real word.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: "No living thing actually thrives ... in environments which are seriously adverse from *its point of view*." Just going by the brief quotes above: "seriously adverse": sure. But stressful: lots of things thrive under stress. Toynbee had a whole theory about human cultures having an optimum level of stress: too much stress and the culture is destroyed or is exhausted just trying to survive; too little and people see no need to work hard so they stagnate; but just the right amount and they develop technology, etc.

Comment: @Jay: The word *stress* has a broad spread of meaning - including what might be better characterised as *stimulation/exercise*. And *cultures* (in any sense) aren't organisms - a human culture may actually be strengthened by war/famine/etc. that kills off the weak. Just as antibiotics, for example, can lead to "super-powerful" micro-organism cultures with evolved resistance. You need to decide if you're thinking of individual or group survival - it makes a big difference in this context, where you can't really consider both at once.

Comment: @Fumblefingers: There's truth in that, but, (a) Many have made the analogy that a lving being is a collection of cells just as a society is a collection of people. To what extent the analogy is valid is no doubt debatable and depends on context. (b) A culture might arguably be strengthened by events that kill off the weak. Again, debatable and depends on context. If a plague killed the weakest half of our population, would we be better off? Surely not in the short term, anyway. But a culture might also be strengthened by events that strengthen the weak.

Comment: @Fumblefingers: In any case, even if we agreed that the idea is not valid, either in general or in the sense that the writer is attempting to apply it, it would not follow that that means it is inappropriate to have a word or phrase for it. We have lots of words for ideas that have proven to be false or impractical, like "flat earth theory", "phlogistan", "planetary atom model", "Democratic Party", etc, etc. You need words to describe erroneous ideas so that you can talk about them. If nothing else, to say "X is false", you need the word X.

Comment: @Jay: On the basis that "Whatever does not kill me makes me stronger", I suppose we can just ignore this *individual/collective* issue and say the quality of being improved by adversity is simply *adaptability*. But I still think Talib is trying to capitalise on people's tendency to conflate the individual and the group.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Could be. As I said, I haven't read the original article, just the brief quote above, so I have no idea if I would think MR Talib a genius, an idiot, a demagogue, etc. After all this discussion maybe I'll read it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't a better word for antifragile than "antifragile".  I suggest that Taleb is more concerned with epistemology than etymology.  I doubt there is a true antonym for fragile in English or any other language because few have grasped the idea that something can improve when mishandled or stressed. While "resilient" indicates recovery from adversity it fails to convey the positive effects of stress that are implied by "antifragile". I support using "antifragile" because its novelty may encourage a deeper understanding of how systems actually respond to perturbations.  If, over the last decade, companies, economies and financial markets had been assessed as being either fragile, robust or "antifragile", our world might be better.

Comment: thanks @DavidR -- I see your point and agree: _I support using "antifragile" because its novelty may encourage a deeper understanding of how systems actually respond to perturbations._

Comment: @DavidR Brilliant answer.

Comment: @mjhoy OP: "few have grasped the idea".  This is so untrue - I have to respond.  Man has always most commonly recognized strength via adversity; training, conditioning, acclimating, adapting, etc.  IIRC, Taleb was responding to a modern prescription for living that is fragile, and he was being antithetical to that; his term really is antithetical to prescribed fragility. He failed to try to understand why the term wasn't there. I think this is because our concepts have always been in relation to inherent strength, and not present condition, meaning there is no such thing as "antifragile".

Comment: 'Vibranium', 'self-annealing', 'self-tempered', 'ever-annealing'?

Answer (score 2):

It may be difficult to find an existing word in English, since none of the existing ones actually match the concept.

Footnote from Antifrailge by Taleb:

> Once again, please, no, *itisnotresilience*. I am used to facing, at the
> end of a conference lecture, the question “So what is the difference
> between robust and antifragile?” or the more unenlightened and even
> more irritating “Antifragile is resilient, no?” The reaction to my
> answer is usually “Ah,” with the look “Why didn’t you say that
> before?” (of course I had said that before). Even the initial referee
> of the scientific article I wrote on defining and detecting
> antifragility entirely missed the point, conflating antifragility and
> robustness—and that was the scientist who pored over my definitions.
>
> It is worth re-explaining the following: **the robust or resilient is
> neither harmed nor helped by volatility and disorder, while the
> antifragile benefits from them**. But it takes some effort for the
> concept to sink in.
>
> **A lot of things people call robust or resilient
> are just robust or resilient, the other half are antifragile.**

(Emphasis added.)

Comment: Another way of looking at your first sentence would be 'the concept does not exist in the real world'.

Answer (score 1):

The Japanese "wabi sabi" is closer than most English words.

Ref: http://www.fastcompany.com/blog/karin-fong/between-spaces/lost-translation-five-words-we-should-import

Comment: I would not say that an answer in Japanese is a good fit for EL&U.

Comment: Wabi sabi is beauty from irregularity or age. It doesn't really fit, unless you replace "beauty" with "benefits" and remove "age". Is there a Japanese word for "benefits from irregularity"?